# Web API, async file uploading works locally, not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using the following tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2, I used the following controller for the base of a file upload call I implemented:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    // Read the form data and return an async task.
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
            }

            // A whole lotta logic to save the file, process it, etc.
        });

    return task;
}
```

To save on space I didn't include the majority of the logic I wrote, since the error happens on the first line within of ContinueWith,

```
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
```

If I run this locally from VS2010, both of the above booleans are false, and the code works perfectly - all of it, even extra few dozen lines I commented out. When I deploy it to a server running IIS7, t.IsFaulted is *always* true. I've never worked with asynchronous calls in C#, and have only done a few simple controllers in Web API...is there something I have to install/configure/etc. on a production server to make it work?

Making it more difficult is the fact that all of the exceptions that are occurring stay in that task (i.e. don't get caught by ELMAH), so I've no idea how to debug what's happening; IIS is also not logging any errors that are occurring in the event viewer...so I'm at a loss to know exactly what's going on. Any tips on how to make this debugging process easier?

Comment: That sounds like some kind of exception is happening. Are you sure the ReadAsMultipart call works as expected? I'd be willing to guess some kind of special configuration value is incorrect on your prod server.

Comment: From what I've read, using the new MVC4 libraries requires *nothing* extra on your existing production environment (aside from deploying the new DLLs, which we are). That said maybe something is borked in IIS; going to spool up a vanilla 2008 server tonight to pursue that avenue.

Comment: Any chance you figured this out?  I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @Telos the first issue was that App_Data wasn't created on the server (oops), the second issue ended up being that the Web API model binder is a bit broken and won't accept all multi-part forms (in particular those posted from Flex), which required using an alternative model binder which I can find if you think that's the issue.

Comment: Not having permissions to app_data was my issue... I had added them, but for the wrong account.  :(  Thanks though!

Comment: @heyseuss have you solved this problem, because I'm also struggling with the same issue. Could you please post your answer if you have resolved your issue.